# Polchinski Vol.2 10.6.4 mutual locality condition

Tags: string-theory

I'm reading String Theory Vol.2 by Polchinski. In the book, Polchinski claimed that
to define a consistent superstring theory, we need to impose several constraints. One of them is the mutual locality condition. A net phase when one vertex circles another,

\begin{equation}
exp \;\pi i (F_1\alpha_2-F_2\alpha_1-\tilde{F}_1\tilde{\alpha}_2+\tilde{F}_2\tilde{\alpha}_1)
\end{equation}

where F is the world-sheet spinors number operator, $\alpha=1-2\nu$ denote the sector NS or R.

I don't know how to get this formula. In my mind, this is like the phase one anyon circles another which decides the statistics.

Please show me the detail. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Let us looking only for the left movers. The Ramond vertex operators ($\alpha=1$) introduces branch-cut for the vertex operators with odd fermion number ($F=1$) in the surroundings. If you rotate the vertex operator $V_1$ around $V_2$ there will be a net phase of

$$
(-1)^{\alpha_1 F_2}(-1)^{\alpha_2 F_1}
$$

the same is true for the right movers.